# I'm too late to remind him

Tags: tense, to-infinitive, perfect-infinitive

Suppose my brother's school is closed today (for some reason). I knew it and he did too. But he forgot it and left for school. After that I say this to our mother:

1. I'm too late to remind him his school is closed today.
2. I'm too late to have reminded him his school is closed today.
3. I was too late to remind him his school is closed today.
4. I was too late to have reminded him his school is closed today.

Which is correct in the context?

Comment: The difference between *I **am** too late [to do blah blah]* and *I **was** too late [to do it]* is trivial (is it a *current* situation, or something in the *past?).* Logically / syntactically  / semantically it makes little or no difference whether you cast ***remind*** as the simple infinitive ***...to remind him*** OR you introduce the "helper verb" ***have*** as an infinitive followed by a Past Participle, as ***...to have reminded him.*** But idiomatically, most native speakers would normally prefer the first *(simpler)* version in such contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that situation, all of 1-4 carry much the same meaning and a fluent speaker might use any of them, although I agree with FumbleFingers that 1 is the most likely choice.

If the event is not so current 1 would not be favored. For example:

> Unfortunately, I was on an anthropological trip to the Amazon and quite out of contact when John decided to visit our parents. I was too late to remind him  that leaving the country would forfeit his visa status. Years later, he is still trying to gain readmission.

Here "I **am** too late" would simply not work.

The use of the participle form (have reminded) makes little difference however long ago the event was. It is largely a matter of style, and most will prefer the shortr form. The form with "have" perhaps slightly distances the speaker from the event, and might be chosen for that reason.